# @AfterMapping mehod is not called in generated class

Tags: mapstruct

I'm trying to customize a mapping use a string to determine an object attribute so I wrote this:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public abstract class ProductMapper {

public abstract ProductInput asProductInputFromIdentifier(String identifier);

@AfterMapping
protected void determineIdentifier(String identifier, @MappingTarget ProductInput out) {
    if (StringUtils.contains(identifier, '?')) {
        out.setExternalId(identifier);
    } else {
        out.setInernalId(identifier);
    }
}
}
```

The generated class doesn't call the **determineIdentifier** method. I found another solution by using directly the Java expression on the **asProductInputFromIdentifier** method but I really want to write a clear code using the **@AfterMapping**.

```
@Mapping(target = "externalId", expression = "java( org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.contains(identifier, '|') ? identifier : null )")
@Mapping(target = "internalId", expression = "java( !org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.contains(identifier, '|') ? identifier : null )")
public abstract ProductInput asProductDetailInputFromIdentifier(String identifier);
```

I didn't understand why it doesn't work Is it because I don't have an Object in method parameter?

Comment: Which version of MapStruct are you using?

Comment: Hello, <org.mapstruct.version>1.4.1.Final</org.mapstruct.version>

Comment: try @Mapper(builder = @Builder(disableBuilder = true))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Method with `@AfterMapping` will be executed at the end of map method and it should have same input parameter as map method for example in below sample

```
@Mapper(
    componentModel = "spring",
    injectionStrategy = InjectionStrategy.CONSTRUCTOR,
    uses = {IdentifierMapper.class})
public interface HistoryMapper {

  HistoryDynamo toHistoryDynamo(History history);

  @AfterMapping
  default void changeReason(History history) {
    System.out.println(history.getReason());
  }
}
```

Refer github working sample for the same https://github.com/rakesh-singh-samples/map-struct-samples/tree/stack-question-60523230/src/sample/mapstruct/mapper

Comment: you can also use an additional argument annotated with `@MappingTarget`. see here for the documentation: https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#customizing-mappings-with-before-and-after

Comment: Yes As I did thank you :)

Comment: I can tell that something like this (a bit more complex) and a @Context in the mapping method, does not work for me. No way I can have the after mapping method called in the generated mapper

Answer (score 8):

In case of having lombok @Builder, the afterMapping will never be called.

The issue is always not resolved.

Check the issue on the official repo [here](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1454)

Answer (score 3):

To solve the problem, I added the  to **ProductInput** to the abstract method parameters as follow (which is not the requirement). As explains @Rakesh in his answer above **Method with @AfterMapping will be executed at the end of map method and it should have same input parameter as map method**, but it can interest others in their case:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public abstract class ProductMapper {

   public abstract ProductInput asProductInputFromIdentifier(String identifier, ProductInput out);

   @AfterMapping
   protected void determineIdentifier(String identifier, @MappingTarget ProductInput out) {
      if (StringUtils.contains(identifier, '?')) {
          out.setExternalId(identifier);
      } else {
          out.setInernalId(identifier);
       }
    }
}
```

But In my case I used the builder = @Builder(disableBuilder = true) to turn off "builders" in MapStruct be it can help someone ;) [Mapstruct Builder](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/Builder.html)
Now the generated MapperImpl calls the annotated **@AfterMapping** method.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the MapsStruct `@Builder` annotation. This one did also the job for me with MapStruct 1.5.5-Final and lombok @Builder annotatade entities. I had to put ``@BeanMapping(builder = @Builder(disableBuilder = true))``above the automated method mapping.

Answer (score 2):

MapStruct doesn't know how to map from `String` to `ProductInput` in your case I would suggest that you implement the mapping method on your own.

e.g.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public abstract class ProductMapper {

    public ProductInput asProductInputFromIdentifier(String identifier) {
        ProductInput out = new ProductInput();
        if (StringUtils.contains(identifier, '?')) {
            out.setExternalId(identifier);
        } else {
            out.setInernalId(identifier);
        }
        return out;
    }
}
```

There is no point in using lifecycle callbacks nor special `@Mapping` annotations to perform a simple mapping like in this example.

Comment: Hello it doesn't work the generated mapper is empty:  @Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2022-02-16T11:32:18+0100",
    comments = "version: 1.4.1.Final, compiler: Eclipse JDT (IDE) 1.3.1200.v20200916-0645, environment: Java 11.0.12 (Oracle Corporation)"
)
@Component
public class ProductMapperImpl extends ProductMapper {
}

Comment: What doesn't work? There is no abstract method that needs to be generated, so the implementation will be empty

Answer (score -1):

As @Filip mentioned, your @Aftermapping method should return the same return type as that of the mapping method.

```
@AfterMapping
protected ProductInput determineIdentifier(String identifier, @MappingTarget ProductInput out) {
    if (StringUtils.contains(identifier, '?')) {
        out.setExternalId(identifier);
    } else {
        out.setInernalId(identifier);
    }
return out;
}
```

I was using Lombok @Builder annotation on my returned object. When I removed that annotation, my code started working.

Comment: My method was returning void and it was working. But after I added ```@Builder``` annotation to ```@MappingTarget``` it stopped working. I had to remove ```@Builder``` from the model to make it work again

Comment: Despite MapStruct doc claims that it works well with Lombok, many weird things happen when Lombok ann. processor comes in. I am thinking on getting rid of Lombok in my mapper project. In my case, I use Lombok's builder in the bean I use for @Context and I never managed to have the after mapping generated with void return.